# What is the best way to create cart in nodejs,expressjs with hbs?

Tags: node.js, express, session, e-commerce, shopping-cart

My question meaning is that what should we use to create cart in e-commerce site in nodejs. Should we direct add the data in mongodb or first use to create session from collected items. What should we do. If the session is the best way to create cart then please suggest me a best way to create cart in sessions thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating an entry in db would be great because you may need to access user cart at any point of time so instead of managing session, managing db would be good idea.

one more suggestion I would like to give is that when user is checking out the cart then before checkout validate the cart.
suppose, user has added any product to the cart and then does not checkout the cart but after some days, user is checking out the cart and the product in the user cart is out of stock then you need to remove that product from user cart or may be the price of that product is changed then also you need to notify user for this before checkout. This type of validations are included in validate cart.

Hope this helps!

Thank you

Comment: You want to say me that entry direct add to db or what sorry i didn't get your point.

Comment: yes, create entry for user cart in db.
create cart collection and order collection.
cart collection will hold all details related to user's cart and when user makes successful payment of cart then that entry should be moved to order collection

Comment: Thanks Alot Drashti kheni for your suggestion.